# Dev Tools Dimensions vs Screenshot Dimensions

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, screenshot, dimensions, developer-tools

I'm trying to resize a bootstrap modal window. In the Chrome dev tools I can see that the width and height are appropriately set by using the following CSS rules:

```
.manage-modal-dialog {
  width: 450px;
}

.manage-modal-content {
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 460px;
  max-height: 460px;
}
```

However, when I screenshot the modal and measure it in a image editing tool, it shows that the dimensions are `562x574`. Admittedly, I may have cropped incorrectly and be off by a pixel or so but that doesn't account for the large pixel difference I'm seeing.

I see this consistently across browsers (tested Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11) and I can confirm that adjusting the `width` and `min-height` in the dev tools adjusts the modal as expected.

What is the reason for this difference? Am I missing something?

Comment: 562/450 ~ 125% so it may be page zoom (which you can reset) or a bug/feature due to system DPI = 125%.

Comment: System DPI was it. Went into display settings and found it defaulted to 125%. Set it to 100% and now the measurements match up. Thanks!